# Mongo DB Atlas Password change for a user created for a cluster

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-atlas

I am new to using MongoDB atlas. I created a cluster and user for it. I forgot the password for that user so that I can provide access to the database through my app. Even though I searched for how to change password, I am unable to do it through MongoDB Atlas UI. Can anyone help on how to do it please?

Comment: Are you logged into mongodb atlas at the moment and can you access the cluster using atlas website - https://cloud.mongodb.com/?

Comment: https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-add-mongodb-users/#modify-database-users